# Kociemba fails to install in Python 2.7, Win10

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, installation, python-module

I am trying to install [kociemba](https://github.com/muodov/kociemba) module in Python 2.7 with `pip install kociemba` but I always get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi1Ri.jpg).

I have searched for similar problem and tried to fix my error using their solution, without any result.

This is what I did:

- Uninstall and reinstall Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and Visual C++ Build Tools
- Add the `stdint.h` file in the directory of `Visual C++ for Python`
- Trying installing `kociemba` (always with `pip`) with administrator privileges in the CMD
- Use Python 3.6 instead of 2.7
- Try installing it on Debian (with virtual machine), without success

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problem with"No module named 'kociemba'"

I think you should install ide visual studio 2022, and install C/C++ pkg.
Maybe kociemba pkg need this ide to run. It worked for me.
Good luck to you.